# Advantages of creating a new Apple ID for Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

I'm developing a iPhone app.
I have a question for people who registered Apple Developer Program.
 

Did you create a new Apple ID for Apple Developer Program?
Or did you used the same Apple ID as the one you use to buy iTunes items (music, app, etc).

Should I create a new Apple ID or use the existing Apple ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wish to keep it organised a good idea would be to create another apple ID that is more "business" oriented but in the end it is your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the blog!
Could you tell me more detail about benefits of creating  a "business" oriented apple ID?